# Strange RStudio/readr/data.table behaviour in notebook mode

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio, readr

This code:

````
```{r load data}
myDT <- as.data.table(read_csv(myDataFile))
```
````

is an .Rmd chunk that is trying to load a relatively large gzipped .csv file in RStudio 1.0.143 (R 3.4.0 (2017-04-21), all packages up to date) for Mac.

When run via `knit` all proceeds smoothly (& quite fast).

When run as a .Rmd chunk it runs much more slowly. If I interrupt it using the 'Stop' button it stops the load and then re-loads the data but much faster before actually stopping. The screenshot below shows the end result when I stopped the first load after 50%.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU7e3.png)

(edit) *The screenshot shows what happened when I waited for the initial load (after pressing 'run' on the chunk) to slowly get to 49% and then pressed 'Stop' on the chunk. Instead of actually stopping, `read_csv()` appears to start the load again (producing the new line of feedback) and this second 'attempt' at data load runs much faster producing `myDT`*.

What is happening and what am I doing wrong? Currently the behaviour makes the code very difficult to run in interactive/notebook mode.

(edit) *Kevin's suggestion of switching off feedback significantly increases load speed*.

Thank you!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `read_csv(myDataFile, progress = FALSE)`?

Comment: it speeds the data load up by a factor of 20 (!) or so but it still appears to do the 'stop - load again' behaviour as myDT is created.

Comment: (after interrupt using the stop button)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'stop - load again' behaviour? (maybe as an edit in the original post?)

Comment: edited for clarity (hopefully)

Comment: Thanks! That's bizarre indeed -- I wasn't able to replicate the error you're describing, but I do see other weirdness when attempting to stop execution of a `read_csv()` chunk.